# How to make a node js console application accessible?

Tags: node.js, terminal, console, accessibility

I want to make a console application using Node.js but I want to make it accessible, i.e be readable by screen readers. I wanted to know what is the state of accessibility for console applications in general and if anyone could point me to relevant resources. I tried Googling about accessibility for console applications and Node.js, but couldn't find much on that.